# How to format OpenAI transcriptions in JSON format with timestamps in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, openai-api, transcription, openai-whisper

```html
import openai


openai.organization = "org-xxxxxx"
openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxx"

audio_file_path =  "/Users/tejaksha/Downloads/dhoni.mp4"

# Note: you need to be using OpenAI Python v0.27.0 for the code below to work

audio_file= open(audio_file_path, "rb")
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
```

In the above code i as able to get the output

```html
{
    "text": "Flat back, just got a little tight to him, he was wagging for it, set up for the slower ball and punished it. The one's going straight down the ground. And MS Daini just taking control."
}
```

But i want as the following format with timestamp how to get using OPENAI transcription?

Acutual format that is required for me is

```js
{
  "transcript": [
    {
      "text": "[Music]",
      "start": 7.39,
      "duration": 4.1
    },
    {
      "text": "once upon a time",
      "start": 16.48,
      "duration": 4.4
    },
    {
      "text": "in ancient china there lived three",
      "start": 17.6,
      "duration": 6.64
    },
    {
      "text": "old monks their names are not remembered",
      "start": 20.88,
      "duration": 6.559
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the OpenAI API does not support such feature. However, you can use the whisper library and return the timestamps.

```py
import whisper
model = whisper.load_model("base")
audio = whisper.load_audio(ASRPage.output_file_path)
result = model.transcribe(audio)
print(result["segments"])
```

This does mean that you need to your own GPU or pc to run the inference.